# Struct value of pointer, array and slice

Tags: reflection, go

I want to have a generic way which will always return the struct value no matter if it is provided as pointer, slice or array.

My approach towards this looks:

```
func main() {
    p := Person{}

    if value(p).Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        fmt.Printf("Error 1")
    }
    if value(&p).Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        fmt.Printf("Error 2")
    }   
    if value([]Person{p}).Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        fmt.Printf("Error 3")
    }
    if value(&[]Person{p}).Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        fmt.Printf("Error 4")
    }
}

func value(m interface{}) reflect.Value {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(m)

    switch v.Kind() {
    case reflect.Ptr:
        v = v.Elem()

        fallthrough
    case reflect.Slice, reflect.Array:
        v = v.Elem()
    }

    return v
}
```

[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ZcHpnvOwoT)

As you can see the problem lays with in getting the struct out of a `slice` or `array`.

**How do I need to extend the above function to get the struct value from with in an array or slice?**

Update: What I want to do is turn `[]People` into `People`.

Comment: You can't just turn `[]People` into `People` because `[]People` can contain many `People` objects and there is no reasonable way (generally) to just merge objects. Try just picking one (the first one?). Also what do you do if the slice is empty?

Comment: I'm fairly sure he's trying to get the struct fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want the type even if the slice is nil, you can use something like [this](http://play.golang.org/p/ol5MMHeei3):

```
func value(m interface{}) reflect.Type {
    t := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(m)).Type()
    if t.Kind() == reflect.Slice || t.Kind() == reflect.Array {
        t = t.Elem()
        if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            t = t.Elem()
        }
        return t

    }
    return t
}
```

About `Type.Elem()`, from http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type:

> // Elem returns a type's element type.
>
> // It panics if the type's Kind is not Array, Chan, Map, Ptr, or Slice.

//**edit** updated the function to work on a slice of pointers as well.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Is there some rule on `.Elem()`? I have problems seeing a pattern in its use.

Comment: It only works on Array, Chan, Map, Ptr, or Slice, I added a reference.

Comment: @bodokaiser I've updated the function to work on `[]*Person(nil)` as well

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you mean by "get out of the slice or array" is that you want the first element (that is, the element at index 0)? If that's what you want, then you should use the [reflect.Value.Index()](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Index) method. For example:

```
func value(m interface{}) reflect.Value {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(m)

    switch v.Kind() {
    case reflect.Ptr:
        v = v.Elem()
        if v.Kind() == reflect.Slice || v.Kind() == reflect.Array {
            v = v.Index(0)
        }
    case reflect.Slice, reflect.Array:
        v = v.Index(0)
    default:
        break LOOP
    }

    return v
}
```

[Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/0DnSn--ZP7)

Note that I also slightly modified the flow logic. You were falling through to the slice/array case from the pointer case. You probably intended for the case condition to be tested again (so it'd effectively say, "if this was a pointer, now check if the thing it pointed to was a slice or an array"), but that's not how fallthrough works. Now it checks the case explicitly.