# Copying field/value from src to dest object

Tags: go

I am trying to copy the fields from one struct value to another, where they have the same field definitions. I have this program:

```
package main

import (

    "log"
    "reflect"
)


func setExistingFields(src interface{}, dst interface{}) {

    fields := reflect.TypeOf(src)
    values := reflect.ValueOf(src)

    num := fields.NumField()
    s := reflect.ValueOf(src).Elem()
    d := reflect.ValueOf(dst).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        field := fields.Field(i)
        value := values.Field(i)
        fsrc := s.FieldByName(field.Name)
        fdest := d.FieldByName(field.Name)

        if fdest.IsValid() && fsrc.IsValid() {

            if fdest.CanSet() && fsrc.CanSet() {

                fdest.Set(value)

            }
        }

    }
}

// and then we main:
func main() {

    src := struct {
        Foo string
        Bar string
    }{
        "dog",
        "pony",
    }

    dest := struct{ Foo string; Bar string }{}
    setExistingFields(&src, &dest)

    log.Println("dest.Foo", dest.Foo)
}
```

I run that, but I get an error:

> reflect: NumField of non-struct type

I can't figure out what that's about.

Here's a playground link:
https://play.golang.org/p/TsHTfAaeKhc

Comment: Beware that you are passing pointers to setExistingFields. You may use `reflect.Indirect()` to get the value that `src` points to or itself in case it's not pointing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25104812/4792552.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
func setExistingFields(src interface{}, dst interface{}) {

    srcFields := reflect.TypeOf(src).Elem()
    srcValues := reflect.ValueOf(src).Elem()

    dstValues := reflect.ValueOf(dst).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < srcFields.NumField(); i++ {
        srcField := srcFields.Field(i)
        srcValue := srcValues.Field(i)

        dstValue := dstValues.FieldByName(srcField.Name)

        if dstValue.IsValid() {
            if dstValue.CanSet() {
                dstValue.Set(srcValue)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Note that you need to do additional checking if `src` field value is assignable to `dst` field type.

Edit: The reason why you are getting that error is because `fields` at that point is a pointer to a struct. You need to get the actual struct value by using `Elem()`.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work: A struct always gets its "schema" (eg. its fields) during compile time... You cannot add more fields during runtime.

I don't see what your exact use case is, but consider something like `map[string]string` or even `map[string]interface{}` to be able to "extend" the content/fields of the thing you are passing around...

Comment: I am not trying to add more fields, I am just trying to modify existing fields, given another object of the same type. The error I get still stands, I updated the OP to make it clearer.

Comment: Before you edited the post, `dest` had had only one field so it'd cause panic in any occasion.